# _.map values from object into field names for another object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

Struggling with the vocabulary to ask this properly, so here is my code and with an explanation following:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Base extends Component {

    render() {
        const { cr, p } = this.props;
        return (
            <tr className='bq-bottom-border'>
                <td className='bq-column-border' colSpan='3'>Base</td>
                <td>{cr.BaseN}</td>
                <td>{'$' + (cr.Base10/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
                <td>{'$' + (cr.Base25/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
                <td>{'$' + (cr.BaseMedian/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
                <td>{'$' + (cr.BaseMean/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
                <td>{'$' + (cr.Base75/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
                <td>{'$' + (cr.Base90/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
}
```

So I want to refactor this. `BaseN` is an integer, `Base10`, `Base25`, etc. are percentiles. I am setting up the FE to allow users to select the percentiles themselves, so need to get rid of the hard coding.

To do this, I moved things like `10`, `25`, etc. into a state object `p` that is being passed down from the parent. It looks something like this:

```
percentiles = {
    p1: 10,
    p2: 25,
    p3: 50,
    p4: 75,
    p5: 90
}
```

I want to then do something like the following:

```
_.map(percentiles, p => {
    'Base' + p
}
```

To generate the field names being used in the `<td>` you see: `cr.Base10`, `cr.Base25`, etc. `cr.` is itself an object that has every 5th percentile.

This is where I am failing to understand how to implement it. I am not able to do something like:

```
_.map(percentiles, p => {
    <td>{'$' + (cr.Base{p}/1000).toFixed(1)}</td>
}
```

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

**EDIT**

So I am trying this, a few other variations, and it comes back as undefined so not sure what I am doing wrong...

```
testRender(percentiles, cr) {
    _.map(_.values(percentiles), p => {
        console.log(cr.Base + {p});
        console.log(cr.Base + p);
    })
}
```

Or:

```
testRender(percentiles, cr) {
    _.map(_.values(percentiles), p => {
        let field = 'Base' + p;
        console.log(cr.field);
        console.log(cr + '.field');
    })
}
```

I can do a `console.log(cr.Base10);` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Ben Smith's answer and this [link](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4QQUB2) helped me arrive at the answer:

Basically needed to wrap the statement in [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)to arrive at the solution:

```
testRender(percentiles, cr) {
    _.map(percentiles, p => {
        let field = eval('cr.Base' + (p == 'n' ? 'N' : p));
        console.log(field);
    })
}
```

The actual values of the fields were logged in the console.

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 2):

Using Lodash, you can create an array from your percentiles object's properties:

let _percentiles = _.values(percentiles);

You can then iterate through this in your call to "map"

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. Still having issues. Please see my modified question.